# Understanding Groups Actions and Homomorphisms

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, normal-subgroups

I am trying to prove the following as exercises.

Let the group $G$ act on the set $X$. We define the $kernel$ of this action as the normal subgroup $K = \{g \in G | \forall x \in X: g \cdot x = x\}$.

(a) Construct an action of $G/K$ on $X$ induced from the action of $G$.

(b) Show that the action $G/K$ on $X$ is faithful.

(c) Suppose $G$ acts non-trivially on a set of size $N$. Show that $G$ has a proper normal subgroup of index at most $n!$.

(d) Show that an infinite simple group has no proper subgroups of finite index.

---

My attempts for parts (a) and (b) are the following though I'm not confident about it. As for the rest, I am unsure how to begin.

For part (a), we show that there is an action $\cdot: G/K \times X \rightarrow X$. Well, we have $e_{G/K} = e_G$ and so $\forall x \in X (e_{G/K} \cdot x = x)$ and given $h \in G/K$, $h = gk$, $g \in G, k \in K$, and so $h \cdot x = (gk)\cdot x = g \cdot (k \cdot x) = g \cdot x$ so $gkx = gx$.

For part (b), suppose there exists $z \neq e_G \in K$, we have $\forall x (z \cdot x = x = e \cdot x)$. But this implies that $z \cdot x = e \cdot x$ and multiplying $x^{-1}$ on the right side of both equalities we have $z = e$ which is a contradiction so it must be the case that  $z = e$.

Comment: Do you know how to express a group action as a homomorphism mapping $G$ to $S_X$?

Comment: I believe so. Let $G$ act on $X$, fix $g \in G$ and consider function $\sigma_g : X \rightarrow X$ and we can consider the mapping $\sigma_g (x) = g \cdot x$. Or is this a group homomorphism from $G$ to $S_X$ rather than $G$ to $X$?

Comment: Let me write up a solution in more detail and post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

In general, when we say that a group $G$ acts on a set $X$, we often times will give some sort of definition that looks like: $g.x = x'$. One way to think about this definition is to consider the group action as a mapping of the form $G \times X \rightarrow X$. However, we can also think of the the group action as a homomorphism that takes $G$ to $S_X$.

Let's call this homomorphism $\rho: G \rightarrow S_X$. Then, for any given $g \in G$, $\rho (g)$ is a bijection to and from our set $X$. Then consequently, the we can express the notation $g.x$ as the following:
$$g.x = \rho(g) (x)$$

This is a very useful way to think about group actions and you should take some time to convince yourself that both definitions are equivalent.

---

**Problem (a)**

When we say that $G$ acts on the set $X$, we are claiming that there exists a homomorphism $\rho: G \rightarrow S_X$. Notice that for any point $g \in K$, it holds that $\rho$ maps $g$ to the identity map in $S_X$. Hence, $K$ is the kernel of the group homomorphism $\rho$.

**Hint:** Use the first isomorphism theorem.